# How to find the maximum tension a wire will experience when a sphere is tied to it in a circular motion?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, physics, classical-mechanics

The problem is as follows:

> A sphere of $0.5\,kg$ of mass is rotating around an axis in a vertical
>   plane as shown in the picture from below. The minimum speed and the
>   maximum speed of the sphere are $2\,\frac{m}{s}$ and $4\frac{m}{s}$
>   respectively. Find the maximum tension (measured in Newtons) that the
>   wire will hold. Assume $g=10\,\frac{m}{s^2}$.

[image: Sketch of the problem]

The alternatives are as follows:

$\begin{array}{ll}
1.&10\,N\\
2.&25\,N\\
3.&20\,N\\
4.&30\,N\\
\end{array}$

I'm confused exactly how to assess this problem. In order to find the maximum tension I believe the equation to get this is the conservation of mechanical energy.

My instinct tells me that the maximum tension will be on the bottom as follows:

Therefore:

At that point the forces acting will be the tension of the wire and the weight.

$T-mg=\frac{mv^2}{r}$

$T= \frac{mv^2}{r} + mg$

What's the speed at this point?. Should i assume $4\,frac{m}{s}$ or $2\frac{m}{s}$ and why?. what's the physical reason for it?.

I felt that (based on experience) that the speed will be at that point maximum. Hence I'll use $4\frac{m}{s}$.

Then the tension will be:

$T= \frac{0.5(4)^2}{r} + 0.5\times 10$

But the problem lies on what r should I use?.

Then I think this might come from the conservation of mechanical energy?.

$E_k+E_u=E'_k+E'_u$

$\textrm{E=Energy at the top}$

$\textrm{E'=Energy at the bottom}$

Now for this I'm assuming that the reference for establishing the height of the sphere is passing through the center or axis of rotation.

$\frac{1}{2}mv^2+mgr=\frac{1}{2}mu^2+mg(-r)$

$\frac{1}{2}(0.5)(2)^2+0.5(10)r=\frac{1}{2}(0.5)(4^2)+(0.5)(10)(-r)$

$r=0.3$

Therefore the radius is $0.3$

And the maximum tension of the wire will be: By replacing the earlier value in the above equation,

$T= \frac{0.5(4)^2}{0.3} + 0.5\times 10$

$T=31.66\,N$

However this answer does not appear within the alternatives.

But If I were to use this formula for the speed at the lowest point=

$v_2=\sqrt{5rg}$ (***How was this formula derived?***)

Then $r= \frac{v^2_2}{5g}=\frac{4^2}{5*10}=\frac{8}{25}$

Introducing this in the earlier equation becomes into:

$T= \frac{0.5(4)^2}{\frac{8}{25}} + 0.5\times 10 = 30\,N\\$

Which does appear in one of the alternatives.

But If I were to use this formula instead:

$v_1=\sqrt{rg}$ (***How was this formula derived?***)

$r=\frac{v^2_1}{g}=\frac{4}{10}=\frac{2}{5}$

Then the radius is different? Why is it so?.

Replacing this value in the earlier equation:

$T= \frac{0.5(4)^2}{\frac{2}{5}} + 0.5\times 10 = 25\,N\\$

And this results into $25\,N$ which is the correct answer. But can somebody help me here?. **Why** am I obtaining two **different** values for the **force** and for the **radius**?. My original method did not worked, why?.

Why does it exist a discrepancy between the radius and the maximum speed and the minimum speed?. What am I doing wrong?.

Comment: I think this is more physics than mathematics. But to give you a hint, $mv_2^2/2=5mrg=3mrg+2mrg$ and $mv_1^2/2=mrg=3mrg-2mrg$.

Comment: There is a problem in the wording of the question. It should not read "... that the wire can hold." Instead, given the fact that you have no idea what the tensile strength of the wire is, it should read "... that the wire will hold." Agree?

Comment: @AdrianKeister You're right. I'm sorry. I had updated the question. But I'm wondering if doing that change will it change the way how this question is approaced?.

Comment: @AnJin Can you ***explain*** how did you get those two equations?. I'm still lost at it. I can spot that you used the centripetal force but from where does it come $5mrg$. Weight is $mg$, where does it come $3mgr$ and $2mgr$? I get that at the top is a difference and the bottom is a sum but I'm still stuck on how did you got those numbers?.

Comment: I don't buy either formula: $v=\sqrt{5rg}$ or $\sqrt{rg}$ off the top of my head. It is true, I think, that if an object is at rest, you get something like $v=\sqrt{2rg},$ but that's not true, here.

Comment: And it's not at all obvious to me why your original CoE approach is invalid. Or your application of Newton's Second in $T-mg=\dfrac{mv^2}{r}.$ That seems correct to me.

Comment: Conservation of energy (the tension is not conservative but does no work) gives $v_\min^2+4rg = v_\max^2$ which gives (using supplied numbers) $r = {3 \over 10}$ and from this $T=31.\dot{6}$.

Comment: The $5rg$ number is comes from computing the minimum bottom speed $v_\max \ge \sqrt{5rg}$ so that there is non negative tension all the way around. This is a minimum however.